# Concatenate dataframe by row with same column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe:

```
df1:
              A       B        
    0        12  some text    
    1        28  some text_1    
    2        28  some text_2   
    3        40  some text   
    4        50  some text  

df2:
              C       D        
    0        11  some text_1    
    1        11  some text_2
    2        12  some text
    3        28  some text   
    4        40  some text   
    5        60  some text
```

This two dataframes are ordered by column `A` and `C` (are float) respectively. 
And I want:

```
 df3
                   A       B        C         D      
        0        NaN               11   some text_1
        1        NaN               11   some text_1
        2        12   some text    12   some text
        3        28   some text_1  28   some text
        4        28   some text_2  Nan
        5        40   some text    40   some text
        6        50   some text    Nan
        7        NaN               60   some text
```

So I want to concatenate dataframes by row with the same column value.

**EDIT 1**
By using `df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A'], right_on=['C'], how='outer')` the result is the cartesian product of all the same rows with `A` and `C` values. This create a bigger dataframe in case, for example if I have in `df1 n` times value `x` and in `df2 m` time the same `x`, the result would be `m*n (m > n)` rows with `x value`.

But I want only to concat the first `n` row of `m from` `df1` with the `n` rows of `df2` and leave the remaining `m`-`n` rows of `df1` with a NaN value

Comment: Why is 'some_text_2' in df1.A:28 not tied to 'some_text' in df2.C:28?

Comment: @r-beginners in `df2` there is only one row with `28`, so only the first row with `28` in ` df1` is contatenated

Comment: It has already been determined that it has been posted, but if you have a column that contains the number of times the value of column A and C appears in each column, you can use concatenate to deal with it.
`df.A:[1,1,2,1,1,1], df,C:[1,2,1,1,1,1]`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this if you want to make sure A, B values in df1 are the same as C, D in df2 (or modify lists to include only one column):

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['C', 'D'], how='outer')
```

Comment: this inserts the row with the same column (`A, C`) value multiple times, and not just the first time