# dataframe concatenation by column value (no outer merge)

Tags: python, pandas

This is a new question after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61968652/concatenate-dataframe-by-row-with-same-column-value-in-pandas?noredirect=1#comment109602276_61968652), with more information

I want to merge two dataframes like the outer join, but I do not want the cartesian product, but only the concatenation, for example:

```
df1:
    A
0   2
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   3

df2:
    B
0   1
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   4
```

with : `df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A'], right_on=['B'], how='outer')` I get `df3:`

```
      A     B
0   2.0     2
1   2.0     2
2   2.0     2
3   2.0     2
4   2.0     2
5   2.0     2
6   2.0     2
7   2.0     2
8   2.0     2
9   2.0     2
10  3.0     3
11  NaN     1
12  NaN
```

But I want:

```
   A    B
0   2.0     2
1   2.0     2
2   2.0     NaN
3   2.0     NaN
4   2.0     NaN
5   3.0     3
6   NaN     1
7   NaN     4
```

just concatenate the first 'm' of `df1` with the `m` of `df2` and dhe remaining values of `df1` 
with a NaN value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the cumulative counts of A and B, and use the combination of the counts with A and B as merge conditions :

```
df1['checker'] = df1.groupby("A").cumcount()

df2['checker'] = df2.groupby("B").cumcount()

res = df1.merge(df2,left_on=['A','checker'],right_on=['B','checker'],how='outer').drop('checker',axis=1)


res 


     A  B
0   2.0 2.0
1   2.0 2.0
2   2.0 NaN
3   2.0 NaN
4   2.0 NaN
5   3.0 3.0
6   NaN 1.0
7   NaN 4.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work correctly. I will make some more test.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try/use the concat method. ex:

```
result = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1, sort=False)
```

You can read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).

Comment: Did you try launching what you wrote?

Comment: No this doesn't give what OP wanted. `print(result)` you'll understand.